# System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error

Tags: asp.net

Our staging web application on .Net 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2 was running smooth for more then 2 months. 
All of a sudden, we started getting error in the application saying:

> Error Message: System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreResults()

This comes whenever my data base query is returning more then ~700 rows. 
Strangely, my production web site (with the same code base as the staging) runs well while connected to the staging data base.

I have tried connecting my staging web server to the production data base (similar copy of the staging data base) and i get the same error.
This error is interminent, some times the page loads, and sometimes I get the error.

If I reduce the number of rows to less then 700, the pages work fine.

The particular Stored Proc is getting called only once in my page.

I did the following:

1. Modified the code to use the command object in **using** block.
2. Closing the connection immediately after the usage is done.
3. Compared the staging and production IIS serve settings, and they looked similar.
4. Same MDAC is installed on both the web servers.

But nothing helps and I still get the error in the staging web server.
The query runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio and takes < 3 sec.

Can anyone please suggest any solution to this?

This is the code base where the Stored Proc is getting called:

```
        string strSPName = SQLSchema.strSQLSchema + SPNames.<Some SP Name>;


 using (conn)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = strSPName;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(SPParams.<Some Param>, SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = <value of Param>;
        conn.Open();

        dsSubmitter = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dsSubmitter);
        if (dsSubmitter.Tables.Count != 0)
        {
            dsSubmitter.Tables[0].TableName = DALConstants.<Table Name>;
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

The SP is quite simple with a select statement and with a INNER join between the master and detail table. The master table has ~400 rows and detail table > 10,000 rows. The SQL Query returns around 4000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue with SqlAdapter, why don't you try installing .net framework again.

clean up solution and rebuild it.